# Moving hl7 files in server with batch script

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to move hl7 files older then 7 days. My script is

```
forfiles /p C:\TEST /m *.hl7* /s /d -30 /c "cmd /c move @file C:\New Folder"
```

pause

I'm getting error like

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.
> The syntax of the command is incorrect.
> The syntax of the command is incorrect.
> The syntax of the command is incorrect.
> The syntax of the command is incorrect.
> The syntax of the command is incorrect.
> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Any help? please.

Comment: Robocopy would also be a good solution for this as it has a move option.  It would also run much quicker than FORFILES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `New Folder` has a space in it and `forfiles` doesn't know how to handle that.

Normally, you'd put paths with spaces in quotes to tell cmd that everything inside of the quotes should be considered a single item. Unfortunately, the entire `"cmd /c move @file C:\New Folder"` is already in quotes, so adding more quotes inside of those quotes is only going to make things worse. The good news is that in `forfiles /?`, there's a line that reads

> To include special characters in the command line, use the hexadecimal code for the character in 0xHH format (ex. 0x09 for tab). Internal CMD.exe commands should be preceded with "cmd /c".

The hexadecimal version of `"` is `0x22`, and if you change your command to `forfiles /p C:\TEST /m *.hl7 /s /d -7 /c "cmd /c move @file 0x22C:\New Folder0x22"`, then your script will work correctly.

Comment: Hi , many thanks. I've should put asterix also between  *.hl7* and it works. the command : forfiles /p C:\TEST /m *.hl7* /s /d -30 /c "cmd /c move @file 0x22C:\New Folder0x22"

Comment: @Beginner - Happy to help. If my answer solved your problem, please click the check mark next to it.

Comment: Hi @SomethingDark, okay i've clicked the check mark.Thanks. have a nice day.